# Give the largest open set where the function $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ne^{nz}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analyticity

Give the largest open set where the function $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ne^{nz}$ is analytic.

Here are the steps:

For the series to converge it is necessary that $ne^{nz} \rightarrow 0$. But $|e^{nz}|=e^{n\Re(z)}$ so it is necessary that $\Re(z)<0$. The series does converge whenever $\Re(z)<0$. Now we have to prove that it is analytic in ${z \in  \Bbb C:\Re(z)<0}$.  To prove that the series converges uniformly on compact subsets of ${z\in \Bbb C :\Re(z)<0}$. suppose $K⊂ \{z \in \Bbb C:\Re(z)<0\}$ is compact then there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\Re(z)<−\delta$ for all $z \in K$. Did I miss anything? How ca I  apply M-test to get uniform convergence on $K$. I appreciate your kind help. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's not a function until you specify its domain. what is the domain?

Comment: I assume that domain is $ \Bbb C $!

Comment: So you think $f(1)$ makes sense?

Comment: My professor did not give any additional information. But we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(z) $converges normally on an open set $U \subseteq \Bbb C$. Is this helpful to complete the proof?

Comment: I remember myself and another person answering this question. I don't know why this has re-appeared. The answer is $\{z:\Re z <0\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your steps, for a compact set $K \subseteq {z \in \mathbf{C}: Re(z)<0}$, we can find such a $\delta >0$ such that $Re(z)leq-\delta, \forall z \in K$. Now, note that $\frac{n}{e^{n Re(z)}}\leq \frac{n}{e^{n \delta}} \forall z \in K , n\geq 1 $. Take,  $M_n= \frac{n}{e^{n \delta}}.$

Let  $$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}M_n=\frac{1}{e^{\delta}}+\frac{2}{e^{2\delta}}+\frac{3}{e^{3\delta}}+...+\frac{N}{e^{N\delta}}=\frac{1-Ne^{-N\delta +1}}{1-e^{-\delta}}$$ Then, $lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}=\frac{1-0}{1-e^{-\delta}}$ which is a finite number. Hence by the $M_n$ test the requirment holds.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have exactly followed the same steps to complete my proof!